# Undefined reference to std::nothrow in libsupc++.a of newlib

Tags: c++, arm, newlib, nothrow

Now I am trying to cross compile Nuttx with libc++ using arm-none-eabi toolchain. Most of things is fine, however some C++ applications have an undefined reference to `std::nothrow`. I found out that `std::nothrow` seems to be defined in `libsupc++.a` in the toolchain:

```
new_handler.o:
00000000 b (anonymous namespace)::__new_handler
00000000 T std::get_new_handler()
00000000 T std::set_new_handler(void (*)())
00000000 R std::nothrow
```

I make sure `libsupc++.a` is linked to my app.
My app references `std::nothrow` as follow:

```
U nothrow
```

I guess the undefined reference happened due to mismatch b/w these names, one has namespace, the other has no namespace.
How can I fix this namespace mismatch?

The following is my link command line:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld --entry=__start -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -g -Map=/usr/src/uros_ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/nuttx.map --cref --defsym __stack=_vectors+1572864 -T/usr/src/uros_ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/bsp/scripts/ramconfig.ld -L"/usr/src/uros_ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/lib" -L"/usr/src/uros_ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/bsp/board"  -L"/usr/src/uros_ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/bsp" \
-o "/usr/src/uros_ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/nuttx"   \
--start-group -lbsp -lsystem -lextdrivers -llte -lexamples -lapps -lsched -ldrivers -lconfigs -lc -lmm -larch -lcxx -lapps -lnet -lfs -lbinfmt -lgraphics -lnx -lcxx -lboard "/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libm.a"  -lsupc++ "/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libgcc.a" --end-group
```

Comment: why are you linking with `ld` rather than `g++`? using `g++` will add all the required c++ standard libraries

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rename the way you reference to nothrow in your app. A `.a` file is an already compiled library, so unless you are able to modify it and compile it again, it is non-modifiable (hence the symbols and references).

The compiler uses the namespace to create unique references ([name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), check this example https://godbolt.org/z/cPkvxm). So you'll have to use `std::nothrow` (with the namespace it was defined), otherwise, you are calling another (and probably undefined) symbol.

If `nothrow` doesn't include a namespace, you would be able to use it as you are doing right now, however, if in the future you decide to create your own `nothrown`, you'll have a conflict (easy to solve, but it takes time and things like nothrownCustom/Customnothrown/nothrown_custom/etc instead of Custom::nothrown).

PD: using namespace for your whole file is a very easy fix, but have a look to this post before doing that: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)